# Php in_array() function doesn't work

Tags: php

hell guys,
I have this code:

```
$_SESSION['product'] value is(I var_dump it for you): array(2) {
[0]=>   string(51) "869-Satin bridal bouquet model "Ocean Sunset"-F0036"   
[1]=>   string(47) "876-Satin Bridal bouquet model "Mexicana"-F0039" 
} 
$sproduct="876-Satin Bridal bouquet model "Mexicana"-F0039";
    if (in_array($sproduct, $_SESSION['product'])){
    echo 'aaaaaaaaaaaa';exit();
    }
```

Why it doesnt work? Is it possible this to be caused due not configured server settings? Thanks

Comment: try ````$sproduct="876-Satin Bridal bouquet model \"Mexicana\"-F0039";````

Comment: you array definition is invalid, you should get an error for that. The `(2)` does not make any sense... Same for the way you note down the keys: `[1]` is invalid... Try this instead: `$_SESSION['product'] = array {1=>"869-Satin bridal bouquet model \"Ocean Sunset\"-F0036", 2=>.....`. but as said: you should get a clear error from php.

Comment: Of course I will get error, this is just var_dump of $_SESSION['product'] to show you its value.. And this code is working on another server thats why I suppose this server i am currently using is not configured well and I was wondering which setting I need to change..

Comment: @arkascha, it wasn't the issue it's just a var dump of the Session. also you defined the variable wrong. you should have used `[]` instead (also dropping the keys which are not neccesary).

Comment: @DanRevah Ooops, right, wrong brackets. Still I think the comment makes sense, since the OP clearly wrote that what is posted is the code. Which is clearly invalid.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sproduct='"876-Satin Bridal bouquet model "Mexicana"-F0039"';
if (in_array($sproduct, $_SESSION['product']))
{
    echo 'aaaaaaaaaaaa';exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try escaping quotes

like this

```
$_SESSION['product'] = array(
  0=> "869-Satin bridal bouquet model \"Ocean Sunset\"-F0036",  

  1=> "876-Satin Bridal bouquet model \"Mexicana\"-F0039" 
);
$sproduct="876-Satin Bridal bouquet model \"Mexicana\"-F0039";
if (in_array($sproduct, $_SESSION['product'])){
  echo 'aaaaaaaaaaaa';exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the $_SESSION you've showed in your question is a var_dump of the session variable, and not how you define the array (if it is how you define your array, you should learn how to define them properly).

your `$sproduct` string variable is defined wrong.

in PHP, strings which are defined by double quotes cannot contain a double quote without an escaping backslash ().

for ex:

```
$s = "foo \"bar\" foo bar";
```

or you could use a single quote instead.

```
$s = 'foo "bar" foo bar';
```

using single quotes is a bit more efficient since the double quotes takes longer to process, since the PHP parser has to read the whole string in advance to detect any variable inside and to concatenate it.

Comment: yes Dan this is just var_dump of the value, but this code is working on another server..